# Add drivers to the CentOS Live CD

Tags: centos, drivers, live-cd

I want to add some drivers to the CentOS LiveCD. These drivers are not present on out of the box CentOS LiveCD. 
So Once I add the the new drivers to the LiveCD, and then boot up the server with the LiveCD then I am hoping that it will recognize the new hardware.

I have been googling around this but haven't found a process by which I could add the drivers to a CentOS LiveCD.

AFAIK, adding the driver will need to re-compile the LiveCD kernel. But just now sure about the process.

Any pointer in this direction will be of great help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: What specific drivers are you looking to add?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS has some [instructions on building a custom Live CD](https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/).

The process uses a [kickstart file](https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/wiki/KickstartFile) to determine what is on the Live CD, so you can perform  any customizations possible through kickstart.